# giving choices for user field in model using a charfield of model

Tags: python, django

I have a CharField department in my model which take choices from a set of tuples named department choices and two foreign key fields of user assigned_to and approval by. How should I limit choices such that assigned_to user belongs to group same as deprtment and approval_by is a super user along with belonging to same group as department.

**Model.py**

```
typechoices = (("DATA",'Data'),("ERROR",'Error'),("NEW_FEATURE",'new feature'),("CHANGE",'change'))
statuschoices =(('open',"OPEN"),('wip',"WIP"),('closed',"CLOSED"),('pending',"PENDING"))
prioritychoices=(('high',"High"),('med','MED'),('low','LOW'))
departmentchoices = (('technical',"Technical"),('allocation',"Allocation"),('operations',"Operations"),('marketing',"Marketing"),('hr',"HR"))
fs = FileSystemStorage(location='media')
def get_upload_file_name(instance,filename):
  return "manage/static/manage/%s_%s"%(str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename.replace(' ','_')) 


class Request(models.Model):
      # user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,related_name="user")
      department = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=departmentchoices,default='technical')
      request_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=typechoices)
      priority=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=prioritychoices)
      description = models.TextField()
      sample = models.FileField(storage=fs,blank=True,null=True)
      approval_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      status = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=statuschoices,default='pending')
      created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
      modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,limit_choices_to= {'groups__name' : department})
      approval_by = models.ForeignKey(User,limit_choices_to={'is_superuser': True,'groups__name' : department},related_name="apprby",blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: I am getting error

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "department" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING department::integer".

is groups__ name an integer

Comment: Is this a fresh model? I mean I have came across such issues during migrations when I have a field A which was earlier a Charfield and then I make it to a ForeignKey. So if there is any thing as such you can update your question with that info as well

Comment: Yes I changed it to integer field and then back to character field bcoz earlier i used groups which give error that group should be integer

Comment: groups as in? Group model?

Comment: i deleted migrations now it no more give that error, but that groups_name = department in limit_choices _to is still not working .Please give some solution to fix it. I am doubting can i even use department field as such

Comment: I haven't made model for groups ,I have simply made some users and given them the groups in departmentchoices by django admin

Comment: I doubt if you can use it like that I mean groups__name, I think you have to use department: department. I am not sure either, but in my opinion this model can be designed in a better and more manageable way.

Comment: what should i use then instead of groups name i tried searching dynamic choices but when in save function i tried self.assigned_to.limit_choices_to = a dictionary it gave error none Type object ha sno attribute timit_to_choices

Comment: I do not think that this will be so easy. Have you looked into django-smart-selects? That offers a quick an nice solution for this.

Comment: django_smart_select is also getting problem